# Unicode text is not displayed correctly in awt Label

Tags: java, unicode, awt

I have the following simple Java test program:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class test3 {


    public test3() {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setBounds(50,50, 400,400);
        Label l = new Label("你好吗");
        l.setBounds(10,100, 50,30);
        TextField t = new TextField("你好吗",20);
        t.setBounds(100,100,50,30);
        f.add(l);
        f.add(t);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test3 t = new test3();
    }
}
```

The output of running this test program is 3 square boxes for the label text, and 你好吗 (how are you as in Chinese) in the text field.

`TextField` and `Label` are awt components, while there is no problem displaying unicode in the text field, not sure how to get `Label` to display unicode correctly.

Comment: Since you are new here don't forget to accept the answer which helped I your opinion most. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label` uses a default font which not supports UTF-8. Just change the font of `Label` to a font which supports UTF-8.

For example you can set the same font of `TextField` also for `Label` with

```
l.setFont(t.getFont());
```

But anyway you should consider to use `swing` instead of `awt` components.

Comment: I tried println the logical font name using getFont().getName(), 
and I have got the same default font setting for all AWT components like Label, TextField, Button, Checkbox.
Even I put in l.setFont(t.getFont()) statement, (though they are already of the same font), 
unicode just wont display on Label, Button, and Checkbox.
I guess, TextArea will display unicode correctly since TextField and TextArea have the same parent class.
Ok, I will use Swing instead, since most components in AWT don't support unicode display. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely an issue with the font that the awt Label uses. You will need to find a font that supports UTF-8 and use that. However, if you use Swing components instead of AWT components it works fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setBounds(50,50, 400,400);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("你好吗");
        l.setBounds(10,100, 50,30);
        JTextField t = new JTextField("你好吗",20);
        t.setBounds(100,100,50,30);
        f.add(l);
        f.add(t);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]